# Reliability Analysis - Interpretation of constant reliability in blocks of a system

Tags: probability-distributions, reliability

I am trying to understand a phrase on the reliawiki website : [Link](http://reliawiki.com/index.php/Basics_of_System_Reliability_Analysis)

Close to the end of the page there is a part talking about blocks with static reliability values. It says that:

> A static block can be interpreted either as a block with a reliability
>   value that is known only at a given time (but the block's entire
>   distribution is unknown) or as a block with a probability of success
>   that is constant with time

I do not understand how to interpret "probability of success that is constant with time". Does this phrase refer to a constant pdf or cdf? If the pfd is constant with time, the cdf is a increasing straight line. I can't imagine what the pdf of a constant cdf would be.

Thank you.

Comment: Let $X_t$ denotes a success $(=1)$ or failure ($=0$) then saying the chance of success is constant in time means, $P(X_t=1)=p$ for some $p$ and all $t$ (whether in discrete time or continuous). By the way, the PDF of an RV is the density function and does NOT give you a probability (there are valid and common PDFs that exceed 1). PDFs intuitively give probabilities per small intervals: $f(x)=P(x< X\leq x+dx)/dx$.

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I m not sure if your comment answers the question. If the texts talks about probability constant in time then it probably means that $P(x < t)= cst $ equivalent to saying CDF is constant with time. So is there a PDF that can lead to such a result?

Comment: If $P(X\leq t)=F(t)$ is constant then since the PDF is the derivative of the CDF then the only PDF possible is $f(t)=0$. What book is this? Also to clarify, I first interpreted $X$ to be a binary value by whether or not there is a success—yet here you measure $X$ in terms of time. So what is $X$? Is it the *time* until the first success or is it whether a success occurred or not? Note the distinction.

Comment: Also, if you insist that the CDF is constant *everywhere* on the real line then this contradicts the property held by all CDFs that $F(t)\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty$. Thus, it must be that $F(t)=$constant almost everywhere.

Comment: Hi again, sorry instead of x i should have used s because x would have been probability that an equipment is operational. As I described in the first line of my original question the phrase comes from the reliawiki website